# Php compare interval numbers

Tags: php, arrays, max

I have this :

```
 $values=array("10","30","40")
    $real_value=22;
```

I need compare if this number it´s max or min between array list of  $values , for example get this , number 22 it´s more big 10 and more litle of 30 and no continue with the include and get interval

I try this but no delimit the interval

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++)
{


if ($real_value>$values[$i])
{
print "".$values."";
}

}
```

I need get for example as values for the number 22 the real_value 30 because 22 it´s more than 10 but no more than 30 or 50 and the interval it´s between 10 to 30

I don´t know how get this i hope some idea from community

Comment: first you need to sort array values in ascending order, then, compare your value against them, once you found one value is greater than your value, then, break the loop and print it...

Comment: And the negative why ?

Comment: negative point .........

Comment: 2 negatives , incredible .....

Comment: only for put question , do you want shoot me also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++)
{


   if ($real_value>$values[$i])
   {
      if($1>0){
         print $values[$i-1]." - ".$values[$i-1];
      }else{
         print $values[$i];
      }
   break;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to change your condition and break when it is `true`:

```
if ($real_value <= $values[$i])
{
  print $values[$i];
  break;
}
```

Comment: No if i need compare the number 22 and have for example 3 numbers and the number for compare it´s 22 i need put this number into the interval of number under 22 and more big of 22 , in this case 22 it´s into as i put into the example between 10 and 30

Comment: @user2174831 `$values[$i]` in the `if` condition will be your `real_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++)
{
    if ($real_value < $values[$i])
    {
        print $values[$i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Define the number added to each step
$increment = 10; 

// The number we're actually dealing with
$real_value = 22;

$current = 0; // Starting value
while($current <= $real_value) { // Iterate, adding $increment each loop
  if($current < $real_value) {
    $current += 10;
  }
}

print' Real Value "' . $real_value . '" has calculated value of: "' . $current . '".';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
1. Add your $real_value to the array.
2. Sort the array.
3. Get the element at index of real value +1.